# How can I convert two dates with different formats to DateTime objects so I can compare them?

Tags: perl, datetime

I need to convert the following strings to [DateTime](https://metacpan.org/pod/DateTime) objects so I can compare them:

```
2016-06-30T09:00:00-04:00
2016-07-01T15:37:25
```

Both objects should use the EST timezone. How can I do this?

Comment: You mean you want to remove the timezone offset? (`-04:00` in your first string)

Comment: @ThisSuitIsBlackNot yeah actually i need to remove that (-4.00) and that "2016-06-30T09:00:00-04:00" of type string and i need to convert to DateTime object!

Comment: Which timezone should the DateTime object use?

Comment: @ThisSuitIsBlackNot EST time for my code.

Comment: @MattRaines Hi, i'm not sure how to get the DateTime object from the answers to the question you mentioned, can you please help me in this? Also, it is a different format than i mentioned.

Comment: Your original question was unclear so I edited it based on your comments. I think I understood what you're trying to do, but please edit further if I got something wrong.

Comment: @ThisSuitIsBlackNot Thanks for editing this! its good now.

Comment: Also note that your original question was a bit of an [XY problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/66377/234299): there's no need to remove the `-04:00` from the first string to convert it to a DateTime object.

Comment: @ThisSuitIsBlackNot Ah, okay! Then, how can i convert that to DateTime Object (object looks similar to "2016-07-01T15:37:25" upon printing the value)?

Comment: `print $dt;`. That's the default output format.

Comment: @ikegami sorry i'm not able to get you! can you please elaborate?

Comment: You asked hwo to print the DateTime so it looks like `2016-07-01T15:37:25`. If `$dt` contains the DateTime object, you'd use `print($dt);`

Comment: This question was marked as a duplicate of a question that didn't even touch time zone conversions, which is a key component of this question.

Answer (score 2):

First of all, `EST` is used to refer to a multitude of different time zone offsets. Presumably, you meant `UTC-05:00`.

Second of all, if one is to perform datetime arithmetic, one rarely wants to deal with offsets; one almost always wants time zones associated with a geographical location (such as `America/New_York`). `America/New_York` would be a suitable choice for use below, but I used the more flexible `local` instead.

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use feature qw( say );

use DateTime::Format::Strptime qw( );

my $format1 = DateTime::Format::Strptime->new(
   pattern => "%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S%Z",
   on_error => "croak",
);

my $format2 = DateTime::Format::Strptime->new(
   pattern   => "%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S",
   time_zone => "local",
   on_error  => "croak",
);

my $dt1 = $format1->parse_datetime('2016-06-30T09:00:00-04:00');
my $dt2 = $format2->parse_datetime('2016-07-01T15:37:25');
```

Then, you can do whatever you want. You mentioned you wanted to compare them, which can be done using numerical comparison operators (e.g. `$dt1 < $dt2`).

The following example converts the timestamps into RFC3339 timestamps (the timestamp format used by internet standards):

```
$dt1->set_time_zone("UTC");
say "dt1: " . $dt1->strftime("%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%SZ");

$dt2->set_time_zone("UTC");
say "dt2: " . $dt2->strftime("%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%SZ");
```

Comment: This gives a error like "I don't recognise the timezone 8. at trydate.pl line 21." when there is a value other than 00 in seconds eg: 2016-07-01T16:32:08-04:00. Why it is so? how to discard this error?

Comment: No, `$format1->parse_datetime('2016-07-01T16:32:08-04:00')` does not produce any error. I don't think that's what you actually passed.

Comment: `my $format1 = DateTime::Format::Strptime->new(
   pattern => "%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S%Z",
   on_error => "croak",
);
my $dt1 = $format1->parse_datetime('2016-07-01T16:32:08-04:00');
$dt1->set_time_zone("EST");
print "dt1: 2016-07-01T16:32:08-04:00" . $dt1->strftime("%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%SZ")."\n\n";`

Comment: The above mentioned is the code i have ran, results in `I don't recognise the timezone 8. at trydate.pl line 21.`. But, if i change the "08" to "00" it runs and gives the output correctly!

Comment: It produces `dt1: 2016-07-01T16:32:08-04:002016-07-01T15:32:08Z` as it should for me. Upgrade your modules? /// Note that `$dt1->set_time_zone("EST");` is wrong, as I previously explained. Do you perhaps mean `$dt1->set_time_zone("America/New_York");` or `$dt1->set_time_zone("local");`?